# Dialog cancel button needs to stop browser event

Tags: javascript, dialog, reactjs

I am trying to display a dialog/confirm when a user browses away from a page/component.

I have the following dialog component which currently fires using a listener:

```
emptyBasket: function () {

    basketChannel.publish({
        channel: "basket",
        topic: "emptyBasket",
        data: {

        }
    });

},
```

OnClick which fires publish:

```
onTabLinkClick: function(e) {

    var url = window.location.href;
    var currentRoute = url.substr(url.length - 6)

    if(this.state.BasketTotal > 0 && currentRoute != 'basket' ){

        basketChannel.publish({
            channel: "basket",
            topic: "openDialog",
            data: {
                dialogTitle: 'Warning',
                dialogContent: 'You have contacts in your basket, are you sure you want to leave?'
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The listener in my dialog component then changes the state and displays the dialog:

```
_listenerForDialog: function(data) {
    this.setState({
        title: data.dialogTitle,
        content: data.dialogContent,
        visible:true
    });
},
```

This works, but I would like to add an ok and cancel button, if the cancel button is clicked I would like stop the event.

How could I attach my component to `e.preventDefault()`?

Can I make this work like the native browser confirm()?

```
 var confirmDialog = confirm("You have contacts in your basket, are you sure you want to leave?");
        if(confirmDialog == false ){
            e.preventDefault();
        } else{
            this.emptyBasket();
        }
```

I am using the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-dialog

**UPDATED**

onClose in current component:

```
onClose(){
    this.setState({
        visible:false
    });

    basketChannel.publish({
        channel: "basket",
        topic: "emptyBasket",
        data: {

        }
    });
},
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your dialog will need to include a button to confirm and a button to cancel. You will then need to catch and handle clicks on these buttons. Looking at the documentation for `rc-dialog` there doesn't appear to be an easy way to do this so it may be manual. There look to be several alternative packages with better documentation and features such as https://github.com/rackt/react-modal

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

There is a 'onClose' on the rc-dialog component, I've updated my post above.

I can get it to fire the publish, but I'm not sure how I can use it to catch and handle clicks. 

Any ideas?

Comment: You can get it to fire but it doesn't look like OnClose gives you any sort of indication which button the user clicked. You would need to build this in to track which button the user actually clicked.